# custom module layout not working

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, module, frontend, layout-update

I've been fighting a while with a problem, but I can't find a solution.

Here is the thing:

Got a module that I need to show in the sidebar of catalog product view so this is my module.xml in `default/default/layout/module.xml` (module.xml is fictional name)

**garantiaextendida.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="garantiaextendida/garantias" name="garantias.banner" template="garantiaextendida/banner.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida>
    </modules>
     <admin>
        <routers>
            <garantiaextendida>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida</module>
                    <frontName>garantiaextendida</frontName>
                </args>
            </garantiaextendida>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <garantiaextendida module="garantiaextendida">
                <title>Garantia Extendida</title>
                <sort_order>72</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <item module="garantiaextendida">
                        <title>Garantia Extendida Admin</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>garantiaextendida/adminhtml_garantias</action>
                    </item>
                </children>
            </garantiaextendida>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <garantiaextendida>
                            <title>Garantia Extendida Admin</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </garantiaextendida>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>   
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <garantiaextendida>
                    <file>garantiaextendida.xml</file>
                </garantiaextendida>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>  

    <global>
        <helpers>
        <garantiaextendida>
            <class>Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida_Helper</class>
        </garantiaextendida>
    </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <garantiaextendida>
                <!-- Set a block definition and lookup directory -->
                <class>Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida_Block</class>
            </garantiaextendida>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <garantiaextendida>
                <!-- This is where we define our model directory -->
                <class>Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida_Model</class>
                <!-- Define a resource to create a custom table -->
                <resourceModel>felisiakluciano_garantiaextendida_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </garantiaextendida>

            <!-- Here's our resource model we'll use to create a database table -->
            <felisiakluciano_garantiaextendida_mysql4>
                <class>Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <!-- Let's define our table, we'll call it with the garantias name, but the real table is felisiakluciano_garantiaextendida_garantias -->
                    <!-- After we define our entity, we can call it with our model by calling felisiakluciano_garantiaextendida/garantias -->
                    <garantias>
                        <table>felisiakluciano_garantiaextendida_garantias</table>
                    </garantias>
                </entities>
            </felisiakluciano_garantiaextendida_mysql4>
        </models>

        <!-- And finally we define our resource setup script -->
<resources>
            <garantiaextendida_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Felisiakluciano_Garantiaextendida</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </garantiaextendida_setup>
            <garantiaextendida_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </garantiaextendida_write>
            <garantiaextendida_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </garantiaextendida_read>
        </resources>
    </global>


</config>
```

What am I doing wrong? Its like the file.xml is not being loaded or ignored. Please help me with this. Thanks a Lot, have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you need to `define layout file` for this at `frontend area` at `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
 <layout>
    <updates>
    <garantiaextendida>
        <file>garantiaextendida.xml</file> <!--  this layou xml  file(garantiaextendida) which is located at your template layout location  -->
    </garantiaextendida>
    </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
```

**Note:** `garantiaextendida.xml`  is layout file which is located at `app/design/frontend/yourpackahe/yourtemplate/layout`
 and code of this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>

<catalog_product_view>

                <reference name="right">
                    <block type="garantiaextendida/garantias" name="garantias.banner" template="garantiaextendida/banner.phtml" />
                </reference>

</catalog_product_view>

</layout>
```

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCH!@ , Totally Missed the <frontend> </frontend> part, youre great